# What replaces the deprecated property this.selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

In creating my first jQuery plugin I want to use selectors inside the plugin code that are confined to the outermost selector. **this.selector** is perfect. It is, however, being taken away. :/  So rather than code a depreciated property I want to use the best practice.

I want to insure that I affect only items within the selector. Right now my plugin has mad spillage. My var panelCount is of course counting the whole page hiding and cycling more than it should etc.

snip...

> ```
>     var defaults = {
>         displayCount: 2,
>         startIndex: 0,
>         panelClass: "panels",
>         hoverClass: "hover",
>         rounded: false
>     },
>     settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
> ```

```
        var panelCount = $("." + settings.panelClass).length; //needs restraints
```

snip

I use the following call to try to make sure chaining works.

```
$('.DisplayWall').metro({displayCount:2,hoverClass:"hover"}).css("color","red");
```

I have a [**fiddle** here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cyberjetx/y9pEV/).

Comment: You can just pass the selector into the plugin as a parameter.  That's the suggestion from the docs: http://api.jquery.com/selector/

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/RmwqL/1/ ?

Comment: Why do you need the selector? you have access to the element itself. Working with the selector severely limits the functionality of your plugin. If it's used on an element with a class, it all of a sudden can only be properly used on that one element, additional instances won't work as individual instances.

Comment: Or why not try something like `$('.next', this)`?

Comment: I don't get it? Wouldn't it be just `$("." + settings.panelClass, this)` to limit the selection to the element(s) passed to the plugin ?

Comment: Thank you all for helping me do it correctly.  ",this" and "$this" as used in Kevin B's fiddle are the answer. Arun's fiddle was 90% there, however, the .panels outside the selector were hidden. I had thought about passing the selector as a param but that seemed so redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The replacement for `this.selector` is to not rely on the selector being used and instead use the element that was selected. Therefore, you should re-implement the `this.each()` and then properly filter your selection per instance.

```
this.each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $('.next',this).click(function () {

    $('.previous',this)

    $("." + settings.panelClass,this)

    //etc...

})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y9pEV/8/

Now, if you had TWO `DisplayWall` elements, they would each work independently.

Don't forget that inside SetDisplay, `this` is Window.